# Is it possible to use va_list for child nodes in a tree structure?

Tags: c, tree, variadic-functions

Is it possible to use va_list to define structure in C? Something like:

```
struct node
{  int value;
   va_list children;
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically you can have a `va_list` as an element of a struct, but it doesn't make much sense. The `va_*` API is very specialized. In particular, there's no public API for adding elements to a `va_list` so you can't exactly do much with it.

As far as consuming code knows, `va_list` get magically populated with the argument lists. They're not meant to be used as generic lists for storing whatever you want. Even if you can trick or maneuver the `va_list` into being usable, it's the wrong path.

---

I would suggest you use either a simple linked list or a vector. Both are very easy to make, even in a generic manner.

Another option would be to just manage the memory directly. This would be a very viable option if you're interested in just assigning the children once. If you plan on dynamically adding/removing children though, a higher level data structure will be easier to work with.

Answer (score 5):

I bet this is not what you want to do.

`va_list` is used for functions. A `struct` might be able use it as a member, but that won't work like you want.

If you want to give unlimited amount of possible children for a tree node, you need to allocate it **dynamically**.

To allocate memory **dynamically** in **C**, you need to read about **pointers**.

You can do it like that:

```
struct node
{
    int value;
    node *children; // "node *" means POINTER TO node.
};
```

Then, in code, you can make a function that will allocate enough space for your nodes, for example:

```
void node_allocate(struct node *n, int amount)
{
    n->children = malloc(amount * sizeof(node));
}
```

After calling that function, struct `node` member `children` will behave like an array (but it's not an array! It's a pointer to allocated memory), with length of `amount`.

At the end of your program, you should deallocate memory your program uses, like this:

```
void node_deallocate(struct node *n)
{
    free(n->children);
}
```

Of course do not just copypaste the code I inserted here! Read about **pointers**, **dynamically allocating memory**, **malloc()** (or **calloc()**) and **free()**!

Answer (score 1):

Technically Yes we can. The following is tested [here.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/G16rF%247)

```
#include <stdarg.h>



struct node
{  int value;
   va_list children;
};

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "It Compiles" but, how to use it..?

Comment: @pst: Umm, I really have not an idea for a meaningful usage.

Comment: "*Technically Yes we can*". That's the best kind of "yes" ;)